# code inside dispatch_get_main_queue block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have few codes like below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"1");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"3");
    });

    NSLog(@"2");
}
```

In console, the console output are: `1, 2, 3`. At first I thought it should be `1, 3, 2` cause `dispatch_get_main_queue` is the main queue, and outside it is main queue as well. Why the output is different?

Comment: Potentially it could make it execute last I think because it has to guarantee to be on the main thread so it probably check the run loop as well.

Comment: I dont get most of that comment I fear ^^

Comment: Even though you were on the main thread the call has to guarantee that it will be on the main thread and processes in the next run loop or the end of the previous run loop. At least I am pretty sure it skips a run loop. I could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dispatch the code in NSLog(3) using *dispatch_async* which will make it be executed asynchronously after the the current synchronous function is done.

---

I'd recommend reading a tutorial on Threading in General and GCD in particular since SO cant&shouldnt fully cover this.

Comment: Inside the block, it's async, outside the block it's sync?

Answer (score 3):

The `dispatch_async` means "submit this block to run on the designated queue when that queue is capable of doing so, but don't block the current thread waiting for the dispatched block to finish, but rather immediately carry on." And since `viewDidLoad` is running on the main thread, the main thread will finish running `viewDidLoad` before it gets around to running the block that you asynchronously dispatched to the main queue.

Comment: This is also why you should never dispatch a boatload of blocks asynchronously and hope the system will figure things out.   By definition, *asynchronous execution cannot be blocked or throttled* as there is no way for the system to know if the first block scheduled may be blocked by the 100th.